# Reopen question about parameter submission via URL vs. post body

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I agree the literal wording of this question makes it look exactly like a question whose answers would be opinion based (so I completely get that has the hallmarks of a question whose answers will only be opinion), but I strongly think it's not a question that elicits opinion-based answers; instead that there are actually clear best practices to follow and, further, ***very*** clear things ***not*** to do (*ever*). That is, that the question is one which can be (and should be) answered purely with facts and logic, not opinion

On these bases, I vote for reopen: *[HTTP POST with URL query parameters -- good idea or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)*

Comment: Wording of the question is unrelated to answers (in addition to explicitly opinion-based)... I don't see why it should be re-opened in the current state...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I edited to clarify

Comment: Consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion),

> An opinion is a judgment, viewpoint, or statement that is not conclusive, rather than facts which are true statements.

> Distinguishing fact from opinion is that facts are verifiable, i.e. can be agreed to by the consensus of experts. An example is: "United States of America was involved in the Vietnam War," versus "United States of America was right to get involved in the Vietnam War". An opinion may be supported by facts and principles, in which case it becomes an argument.

The [help centre FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) says:

> Opinion-based - discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well.

> > **This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.**

Is there any proof that it attracted answers with opinions  rather than facts and citations after decades? Most answers there  explicitly mention the specification documentation they're referring to. I don't think  it attracted any opinion based answers.

[Stackoverflow help/don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) says:

> If your **motivation** for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Notice how article asks to examine  the motivation and not words. Was the OP asking for a discussion? No. OP is asking: "Is it a good idea?", "Are there any advantages or pitfalls?" The answers clearly state that It is a  not a bad idea and there isn't any pitfalls and that it is actually recommended.

Even if you're bent on semantics and think the question is open-ended or subjective, Subjective questions are actually allowed in SO. The [linked  official blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) asks us to score the question based on 6 factors:

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
- tend to have long, not short, answers
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
- invite sharing experiences over opinions
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
- are more than just mindless social fun

I think this question scores a perfect 6/6 in this case.   It inspired  answers that explained why. It attracted long answers. It has a impartial tone. I don't think it's asking for a opinion or experience, but a potential pit fall. The question itself references a spec sheet- implying answers need to be backed with  facts and references. It's not mindless social fun.

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

- every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
- your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
- there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
- you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
- your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Every answer to this question  is not equally valid. Answers that say it's okay to use GET  in this case are downvoted/deleted. Answer is not provided with the question. There is a actual problem - A critical approach that may result in unintended side effects. It is not a hypothetical question, but a real world scenario. It's not a rant in disguise.

Voted to reopen!